# Qt "The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the operating system"

Tags: c++, qt

I can see this error displayed by my application, I'm running in the debugger and the application halts on the same line when this error is displayed.

If there any further information I can find to give a clue as to why this is being displayed?

The code looks fine, all the pointers and variables look correct, but something is causing a problem, the code:

```
    pobjPainter->setBackgroundMode(Qt::OpaqueMode);
```

pobjPainter is a pointer to an instance of `QPainter`, it has been set-up and is active.

I have been converting the application from `QWidget` to `QOpenGLWidget` and this is a work in progress, so I expect there to be a few issues, but is there any further information or help other than this rather cryptic and not very helpful message?

[image]

QPainter is created as follows, this is called in the paintGL method and the object is derived from public QOpenGLWidget, protected QOpenGLFunctions:

```
    //Get painter object
    QPainter objVisible;
    //Set-up the painter
    objVisible.begin(this);
```

It is then passed down to the render routine for each object type:

```
    renderText(&objVisible, &rctGeom, &rctInterior);
```

Finally I call:

```
    objVisible.end();
```

Before exiting.

This screenshot shows the stack trace in more detail, it looks like the crash occurs in one of the openGL routines:

[image]

Comment: What is the signal?

Comment: @MartinBonner, SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault

Comment: Is the line of code shown really the deepest point of the call stack?  If so it may be that `pobjPainter` has become invalid for whatever reason (UB elsewhere?).

Comment: In that case, pobjPainter is almost certainly not pointing at a correctly constructed QPainter.  Either the pointer is completely corrupt, or the vtable is corrupted (and you have problems actually calling `setBackgroundMode`) -this only applies if the function is virtual, or the object contains invalid values, and the SIGSEGV is actually happening inside setBackgroundMode, but you don't have a debugging copy of Qt.

Comment: I've added a screen shot, I'll edit now and add the code showing the creation of the QPainter context.